# What is the origin of "bored out of my skull" phrase?

Tags: phrases

What is the origin of "bored out of my skull" phrase? I've seen it used quite a few times recently, but cannot pinpoint it to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED’s definition of *bored out of one’s skull* is ‘beside oneself with boredom, bored stiff’. It is slang. The earliest citation is from 1967:

> 12 good men and true, glumly spruce, resigned to a long haul and
>   bored, bored out of their skulls.

Answer (score 1):

'Bored out of my mind' is the usual UK expression. To be 'out of one's mind' means to be mentally ill in some way. So I suggest that 'bored to the point of it driving me mad' might be a suitable alternatively exaggerated way of saying the same thing.

Comment: They do not project the same imagery, though.